# how to use Gulp to concat different js with different set of js , then pipe minify/uglify to different bundle?

Tags: gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-uglify, gulp-rename

what I want to archive with Gulp is:

1. For example I am currently editing `editing.js`
2. If it has been changed/saved, then take `base1.js`,`base2.js`,`base3.js` out, concat them with my `editing.js` in order like `base1.js`,`base2.js`,`base3.js`,`editing.js`
3. Minify and uglify them
4. Finally rename this file with extension like 'editing.min.js'.

   ```
   gulp.task('minify-js', function(){
       gulp.src('static/src/*.js')
           .pipe(concat('static/src/base.js'))
           .pipe(uglify())
           .pipe(gulp.dest('static/dist'));
   });
   ```

And in my case I have multiple source file to be concatenated to multiple bundled files.

What I am failing to archive is to rename to the filename I am currently editing, e.g `ex1.js` to `ex1.min.js`, it always bundled into one only file.

New to Gulp, hope some help, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, something like this should do it:

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('minify-js', function() {
  return gulp.src([ 'static/src/*.js', 'editing.js' ])
             .pipe(concat('editing.min.js'))
             .pipe(uglify())
             .pipe(gulp.dest('static/dist/'));
});
```

As you can see, there's no need to rename because `gulp-concat` already requires you to specify an output filename.

**EDIT**: here's another take. It watches for changes to any `.js` files (with some exclusions; instead of using `**/*.js` you may be able to specify a particular directory where your source files live to limit to amount of possible matches). When a file changes, it will concatenate the `base*.js` files *and* the file that was changed, and use the filename of the changed file as a base for the minified filename (`foo.js` → `foo.min.js`):

```
var gulp   = require('gulp');
var path   = require('path');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('minify-js', function() {
  // Watch for changes on JS files, but exclude some of them.
  return gulp.watch([ 
    '**/*.js', 
    '!static/src/base*.js',
    '!node_modules/',
  ], function(ev) {
    // Watch for changes to the files.
    if (ev.type !== 'changed') return;

    // Determine 'minified' filename.
    var basename = path.basename(ev.path);
    var extname  = path.extname(basename);
    var minname  = basename.replace(extname, '.min' + extname);

    // Run the uglify chain.
    return gulp.src([ 'static/src/base*.js', ev.path ])
        .pipe(concat(minname))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('static/dist/'));
  });
});
```

Comment: sorry seems I have been make it not so clear. but really thanks. I think I want the `editing.js` to be whatever I am currently editing under the `src`, and gulp will automatically concat the base file with the editing one then pipe to the dest. I think I am just not sure how can I let gulp remember the file I am editing at the first place and then take the base file out, concat with the editing one,  finally get the editing one's file name then rename...

Comment: @strangeline it might be possible to use `gulp.watch()` to detect file changes (which would trigger when the file that you're editing is saved). Not sure what you mean by _"and then take the base file out"_, though, perhaps you can edit your question to explain (also useful for others)?

Comment: Sorry for the late, I have edited the question. can you understand what I want to archive now?  _I am not a English speaker, really sorry for the confusing part_,